# Action of $Sp(1)$ over the sphere $S^7$

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Consider the Hausdorff space $S^4 = \mathbb{HP}^1$ and the topological group $Sp(1)$ (identified with the unit quaternions), the cover $\{V_j\}_{j \in J} = \{U_1, U_2\}$ of $\mathbb{HP}^1$ where $$U_1= \{[q^1, q^2] \in \mathbb {HP}^1; q^1 \neq 0 \}\ \ \text{and} \ \ U_2= \{[q^1, q^2] \in \mathbb {HP}^1; q^2 \neq 0 \}$$

and the transition functions $g_{ji} : U_i \cap U_j \to Sp(1)$ for $i,j= 1,2$ are determined by $$g_{12} ([q^1,q^2]) = (q^2/|q^2|) (q^1/|q^1|)^{-1}$$

By the **Reconstruction Theorem** there exists an $Sp(1)$-bundle over $S^4 = \mathbb {HP}^1$ with transition functions $\{g_{11}, g_{12}, g_{21}, g_{22}\}$.

On the other hand consider the usual Hopf bundle $(S^7,\mathbb{HP}^1, \mathcal P, S^3 )$ where $\mathcal P: S^7 \to \mathbb{HP}^1$ is given by $\mathcal P (q) = [q] = [q^1,q^2]$ (restriction of the quotient map that determines the equivalence relation $\sim$ in $\mathbb{H}^2 -\{0\}$ to the sphere $S^7$) where the transition functions $g'_{ji} : U_i \cap U_j \to Sp(1)$ for $i,j= 1,2$ are determined by $$g'_{12} ([q^1,q^2]) = (q^1/|q^1|) (q^2/|q^2|)^{-1}$$

**Question:**

> Show that the underlying locally trivial bundle for the $Sp(1)$-bundle over $S^4 = \mathbb {HP}^1$ is the same of the Hopf bundle, but the action of $Sp(1)$ on $S^7$ is different. Describe the action.

**Thoughts:**

$1)$ From the Reconstruction Theorem we have that the total space $P$ is the set of all equivalence classes $$[x,g,j] = \{(x,g_{kj}(x)g, k) ; k \in \{1,2\} \ \ \text{and} \ \ x \in U_j \cap U_k\}$$ 
I couldn't show that $P$ is the sphere $S^7$. The local trivializations for the $Sp(1)$-bundle are $$\begin{align}\Phi_j : U_j \times Sp(1) &\to \mathcal P^{-1}
(U_j)\\ (x,g) &\mapsto [x,g,j]\end{align}$$
while for the Hopf Bundle we have

$$\begin{align}\Psi_1 : U_1 \times Sp(1) &\to \mathcal P^{-1}(U_1)\\ ([q], y) =([q^1,q^2],y) &\mapsto (|q^1|y, q^2(q^1)^{-1}|q^1|y)\end{align}$$

similar to $\Psi_2$.

I can't see how $\Phi_1 = \Psi_1$.

2) The action $\sigma : P \times Sp(1) \to P$ is given by $\sigma (p,h) = p \cdot h = [x,g,j] \cdot h = [x, gh, j]$. Which I couldn't describe on $S^7$. So far, I understand that $\sigma$ acts on values of the group $Sp(1)$ alone where the action $\sigma'$ given by $\sigma((q^1,q^2), h) = (q^1,q^2)\cdot h=(q^1 h, q^2 h)$, for *any* $q^1, q^2 \in \mathcal P^{-1} (x)$, where $x \in S^4=\mathbb {HP}^1$ acts on elements not necessarily from the group $Sp(1) = S^3$. Is this conclusion anywhere near of what is happening here?

Comment: I understand that you'd like an answer to the question and thus want to prevent it from being forgotten, but please do not make pointless edits to bump the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer And here we are, a month later, and nothing. Because I can't prevent this question from being forgotten.

Comment: That's a pity, because it's a well-asked question. You could place a bounty. Or make some not pointless edits, like adding a link to the reconstruction theorem perhaps, or maybe you can think of a further tag that is relevant to the question. Or you could ask in the [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) whether somebody can help.

Comment: So you're trying to compare the $Sp(1)$-bundles with inverse transition functions. Why do you expect these would be topologically the same? (For example, if we consider the Hopf bundle on $\Bbb CP^1$, it has Euler class $-1$ and its inverse has Euler class $+1$.) I guess the point is that for $SU(2)$-bundles, the bundle and its inverse will have the same Chern classes. So isn't it going to just be a question of a left action versus a right action of $Sp(1)$ on the total space?

Comment: @TedShifrin If the action is different I suppose they must be topologically different. Locally though, they should behave similarly since they locally trivial bundle of the same group over the same base space. Isn't this reasoning correct?

Comment: I totally mistyped there. I meant the bundle and its dual, and the transition functions of the dual are the *transpose* of the inverse of the matrix. ... So what I said was probably just wrong. I need to think a bit more.